# Line Break from SQL Server Export Data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Thanks for looking into my post. I have below issue while exporting data from SQL Server.

I am exporting data from a SQL Server database, comma as column delimiter and `CR|LF` as row delimiter into a csv file.

If I run the query in SQL Server, it's showing column in the grid correctly but if I use Excel or Notepad++, the columns are showing in next line. It's not formatted properly.

How to avoid line break from SQL Server exported data in CSV file?

Please share your thoughts on this one.

Comment: Reminder: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 is out of support. You should upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: You have a `CR` carriage return and a `LF` line feed as a row terminator. Remove the `LF` and see what you get.

Comment: @SS_DBA Still having the same issue

Comment: Interesting... can you show the query you are using to export this? And how are you exporting from SQL?